# is there an enumerator find method in python?

Tags: python

In Ruby, you can use the `#find` method to short circuit after finding the first instance in an array that matches a particular criterion.

```
arr = [5,6,7]
arr.find { |n| n % 2 == 0 } #=> 6
```

Is there an equivalent in Python? Or do you need to use a for loop? I'm trying to avoid this:

```
arr = [5,6,7]
for n in arr:
  return n if n % 2 == 0
```

Perhaps there's a solution with generators? Or perhaps for loops are simply the only pythonic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Perhaps there's a solution with generators?

Yes, you can use a generator and call `next` on it. Returns the first item matching the criteria and raises a `StopIteration` error if none:

```
next(n for n in arr if n % 2 == 0)
```

Python also allows you to pass a default return value in case none of the items match the filter criteria thereby suppressing the error:

```
next((n for n in arr if n % 2 == 0), None)
```

Comment: It's probably useful to say _which_ error gets raised if nothing is found so OP knows how to catch it :-)

Comment: Yep, `None` is really the best default value to return since `nil` is returned from the `#find` method in ruby.